# Realizing Three States By Storing Values in Single Column In DB Table

Tags: database, data-modeling

I Have List of Products Displayed in Web Page.

Each product is identified by unique product id in database.

[image]

Initially when the page loads its would be shown as Both tick and Cross under every product (Image 1)

Once the User click Tick Symbol for particular product I will display it as Interested (Image2)

When the User click Cross Symbol for particular product I will display it as Not Interested (Image3)

I should load the user last selected preference every time the page loads by storing the user name and productId for which the user is Interested.

This remains simple when there are only two states where the user might either be interested or not interested since i will store all the interested ProductaIds in DB and Use them to load user preference.That is I will apply class Interested for all the ProductIds which are in DB and NotInterested class for all those Ids which are not In database.

Now the third state is the one for which the user never touched - Image1.

I already have a DB Table Like Below

```
  CREATE TABLE UserPreference(
      UserId INT,
      Interested_ProductsId VARCHAR(150)
  );
```

I am Storing the Interested_ProductsId as CSV Product Ids (i.e) 5,75,2,15 are all product Ids

Now my question is it possible to realize the third state(Image1) in the CSV.I am storing only ProductsIds in which customer interested.How to realize the ProductsId in which customer is Not interested(Image3) and customer never clicked(Image1).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible: Introduce a new column:

```
Type tinyint not null
CHECK (Type in (1, 2, 3))
```

And define type as one of your three states.

You can associate arbitrary data with your join table items. You basically promote them to "entities" that way.

Comment: I already have ProductsInterested CSV as 1,5,6,45,41  Now how do i associate these Ids with the Three States which you said in the above column

Comment: Can you make the CSV identical to the table by adding the same new column?

Comment: I am Sorry to ask you again I dont Understand what u  r coming to say.Please forgive me. Would you mind if i ask u to add table Structure